# Problem regarding database in webos 3.0 ENYO Sqlite

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, webos

I am new to develop touch pad applications. I am using Enyo framework and sqlite database. I have tried example given in the doc but it seems that the data is stored temporarily. As soon as i refresh the browser or recompile my app the data is lost. I have following queries regarding database:

1. I want to create database separately, not in the application by `openDatabase()` method.
   I want to use this database in my application, So where to locate this database in my
   app and how to connect to this database?
2. I was also not able to locate where my database is created in my app?
3. I want to create connection to the database and access data from the tables on load of
   the application. I know there is application on load event but still was not able to do
   that..

It is very basic things that should be known to create any application on any platform. If anybody have any knowledge on above things then please help. It will be better if someone can provide an example. I am waiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested on SO, i answered this question over at the Palm Developer Centre. To create the DB on app launch, you can override the Kind's ready method.

```
ready: function(){

         // Open the DB
         var db = openDatabase("ext:someDB", "1.0", "someDB", 50000);
}
```

https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15996